# auth-password-store for ftp over tramp

Tags: tramp, passwords, ftp

When accessing remote ftp server with tramp

`C-x C-f /ftp:user@host#port/`

tramp asks me for password. I also use auth-password-store to store passwords in a `pass`-compatibale fashion, that is, host is specified in a filename of a gpg-encrypted file containing password on its first line. However, tramp (or maybe it's AngeFtp?) keeps asking for password, even though I've created a `host.gpg` file in my password store.

- I tried symlinking `ftp:user@host.gpg` to the password file.
- I tried symlinking `host#port.gpg` as well as `ftp:user@host.gpg` and `ftp:user@host#port.gpg`
- auth-password-store and tramp work fine together for `C-x C-f /sudo::/` command, that is, it does find the appropriate file in my password-store and requests my gpg password then
- auth-password-store works fine with symlinks to genuine password files (which is to be expected, I guess?)
- I tried adding `protocol: ftp` record to password file

How do I make tramp recognise my password-store password? Should I file an issue to tramp, or maybe to AngeFtp developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tramp forwards all ftp-related requests to `ange-ftp`. This uses the native ftp client on your local machine.

Therefore, passwords can be stored only in `~/.netrc`. I doubt that this will be changed in Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following two lines in my init.el:

```
(setq auth-sources "~/.secrets/authinfo.gpg")
(setq ange-ftp-netrc-filename auth-sources)
```